# c++ error: expected class-name before '{' token

Tags: c++, catkin

[screenshot of Pose.hpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxtX8.png)
I am trying to catkin_make a simple package and I am getting the error

```
.../Pose.hpp:17:1: expected class-name before token...
.../Odometry.cpp:12:3: expected class-name before token...
```

The responsible Pose header file is sampled here as:

```
#ifndef POSE_HPP
#define POSE_HPP
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>
#include "ros/serialization.h"
#include "ros/builtin_message_traits.h"
#include "ros/message_operations.h"
#include "ros/message.h"
#include "ros/time.h"


namespace turtle
{//line 17
template <class ContainerAllocator>
struct Pose_ : public ros::Message
{
  typedef Pose_<ContainerAllocator> Type;

}; // struct Pose
...
} // namespace turtle
```

while on the referred header file is referenced in odometry.cpp shown as

```
#include <geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <robot_localization_demo/odometry.hpp>

namespace robot_localization_demo {

  TurtleOdometry::TurtleOdometry(ros::NodeHandle node_handle, double frequency):
    node_handle_{node_handle},
    turtle_pose_subscriber_{node_handle_.subscribe("turtle1/pose", 16, &TurtleOdometry::turtlePoseCallback, this)},
    turtle_twist_publisher_{node_handle_.advertise<geometry_msgs::TwistWithCovarianceStamped>("turtle1/sensors/twist", 16)},
    frequency_{frequency},
  {//line 12
    ;
  }
```

and odometry includes Pose as well. 
what am I missing here?

Comment: Done. I am note sure if I follow your question. Should cite the link to ros::Message here?

Comment: I _think_ you marked the wrong line. I suspect it's the `{` after `struct Pose_ : public ros::Message` that is line 17 and if that's the case my answer below is probably correct. ... and yes, please include the link to the `ros::Message` documentation in the question.

Comment: I added the screenshot of the Pose.hpp anyway to the beginning of the post.

Comment: In that screenshot, line 17 is the line I thought it was and not the one you've marked in the question. Did you find the documentation for `ros::Message`?

Comment: http://wiki.ros.org/Messages ?
Yes, are you implying that the Pose.msg is not fed properly?

Comment: I meant the documentation for the class `Message` in the `ros` namespace. My answer implies that the class definition doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You still have the wrong line marked in the question btw.

Comment: If you look in your version of `ros/message.h`, is the `class Message` definition made within a `#if 0` ... `#endif` block?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I managed to solve the issue by defining another class in my namespace. I am not sure why this happens exactly. But it seems that when the the Pose.hpp file includes manipulations of standard ROS libs (headers), the conflict is shown a this error. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Oh, that's hard to say. I think you'd better ask a separate question for that and include as much deatails as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation for [`ros::Message`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Message.html) says:

> This base-class is deprecated in favor of a template-based serialization and traits system.

In the [official source code](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/roscpp/html/message_8h_source.html) it looks like it's still defined, but in a contrib version I found, the whole [class definition](https://github.com/NimbRo/nimbro-op-ros/blob/master/src/nimbro/contrib/roscpp/include/ros/message.h) is removed by `#if 0`:

```
namespace ros {
#if 0
class Message {
    //
};
#endif
}
```

So, you most probably need to find a different base class.